# Flask + SQLAlchemy adjacency list backref error

Tags: python, orm, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following model:

```
class Category(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'categories'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(id), nullable=True)
    level = db.Column(db.SmallInteger)
    name = db.Column(db.String(200))
    children = db.relationship('Category', backref=backref('parent', remote_side=id))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Category %r>' % (self.name)
```

This doesn't seem to work. I always get the following error:

```
NameError: name 'backref' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On this line...

```
children = db.relationship('Category', backref=backref('parent', remote_side=id))
```

You are using the attribute `backref`, but have never defined it. You would get a similar error if you had wrote...

```
children = db.relationship('Category', backref=photosynthesis('parent', remote_side=id))
```

Same problem: Python doesn't know what "photosynthesis" is.

So, what is backref actually supposed to be in your code? Turns out it's a [function that is part of SQLAlchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.backref). Like many of these functions (e.g., the "relationship" function you are using), Flask-SQLAlchemy will provide to you an alias so you don't need to import them directly.

You can use the [docs](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/models.html#one-to-many-relationships) as your guide. Instead of `backref=backref`, you want `backref=db.backref`.

Comment: Oh, right...haven't thought of that. It's my first python project. I'll try this out an report back.

Answer (score 4):

You have to explicit what backref is. You can do it with this import:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import backref
```

Comment: This answer is superior because it doesn't beat around the bushes. +1